# Mock globally available object for jest tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a js module which uses a reference to a custom window property. Basically, in another file I have:

```
    const component = window.externalFunctions.component;
```

The js module I'm testing uses this `component` without any kind of imports and is being loaded in the app dynamically by creating a `<script>` in the document. There is an example function inside:

```
const getDate = (date) => {
    let currentTime = date;
    currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + component.clientTimeZoneShiftInMinutes*60*1000);
    return currentTime;
}

export const getShift = (date) => {
  const currentDate = getDate(date);
  .....
}
```

When I run a simple jest test case, it says: **ReferenceError: component is not defined** inside the module. In my helpers.test.js I have:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    const component = {
        clientTimeZoneShiftInMinutes: 180,
    };
})

test("Choosing correct shift", () => {
    expect(getShift("2022-12-22T00:00:01")).toBe(1);
});
```

but apparently it doesn't work. I also tried specifying `globals` in jest.config.js, no luck.

How can I mock such a globally available object for jest tests?

Comment: The `const` is scoped to the closure. You need to declare the variable higher in the scope hierarchy.

Comment: Tried this too, didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue with the following code in the test-case:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    global.window = Object.create(window);
    Object.defineProperty(window, "component", {
        value: {clientTimeZoneShiftInMinutes: 180}
        ,writable: true
    });
    const component = window.component;
})
```